# Setup a non-GUI user?

Tags: gui, users

It's possible to create a user such that

- Login is possible via command line interface, e.g. `tty`, `ssh`, etc;
- Login is impossible in GUI, e.g. `lightdm`, `gdm`, etc;
- It has password, ideally also has home directory.

Comment: What is the purpose? what if they logged in and then used `startx` to bring a GUI up? you want it only for specific users?

Answer (score 2):

In **Ubuntu 16.04**,

you can configure the `access.conf`  file according to your needs.

First, create a standard user (without Admin privileges). 
Then edit the file `/etc/security/access.conf` and add a line that will disallow any local logins except the tty that you will define.

In the following example, the user with username localuser can log in (in local machine) only from tty1.[image]

```
- : localuser : LOCAL EXCEPT tty1
```

Now we need to **activate the access.conf** file.

*Here is the Trick* on how to activate in Ubuntu.

For some reason, when I tested this on my Ubuntu 16.04 configuring the default /etc/pam.d/login file, (the pam_access.so line already exist there, and I just uncommented it) it didn't work.

But it did work when I added the line in `/etc/pam.d/common-account`

Edit the file and insert the following line **below** `pam_deny.so`.

```
account required                        pam_access.so
```

[image]

No restart of any service is needed. Just log out and test if the new user can log in from Lightdm, GDM or any Display Manager you have.